# In Roslyn ToMinimalDisplayString method, what does 'position' argument mean?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm looking at this method in `ISymbol`:

`string ToMinimalDisplayString(SemanticModel semanticModel, int position, SymbolDisplayFormat format = null);`

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.symboldisplay.tominimaldisplaystring?view=roslyn-dotnet-4.3.0#microsoft-codeanalysis-csharp-symboldisplay-tominimaldisplaystring(microsoft-codeanalysis-isymbol-microsoft-codeanalysis-semanticmodel-system-int32-microsoft-codeanalysis-symboldisplayformat)) says that position is "A position in the source code (context)."  What is the unit of measure of position?  Is it a line number?  In other words, can I use this value:

`mySyntaxTree.GetLocation(myNode.Span).GetLineSpan().StartLinePosition.Line;`

**Edit:**
Some non-definitive experimenting suggests that it is not a line number, because when I use the above value, the method does not remove unnecessary namespaces.  But the following value seems to give the right behaviour:

`myNode.Span.Start;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you did figure out the "position" is the zero-based index of characters like our start/end span. The API never really accepts lines for the most part, since those are generally user-displayed only.